# Let X be a set with an associative binary operation ◦ with identity e. Suppose every element of X satisﬁes x ◦ x = e. Prove that ◦ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having problems trying to figure this out. It seems very straight forward, but I don't know what I should do to prove it. Let $X$ be a set with an associative binary operation $\circ$ with identity $e$. Suppose every element of $X$ satisﬁes $x \circ x = e$. Prove that $\circ$ is commutative.

Answer (score 6):

For all elements $a,b$ , we have

$$a\circ b=b\circ b\circ a\circ b\circ a\circ a=b\circ (b\circ a\circ b\circ a)\circ a=b\circ(b\circ a)\circ (b\circ a)\circ a=b\circ a$$

Comment: I upvoted your solution!  I liked your solution better than mine, because your solution shows that the problem can be done without using the machinery of groups.

Answer (score 3):

We have a set $X$ with an associative binary operation $\circ$, with an identity $e$, such that for every $x\in X$, $x\circ x=e$. It follows that $(X,\circ)$ is a group, and that for all $x\in X$, $x^{-1}=x$.

We can now get an elegant proof by using the fact that for any group $G$ and any $a,b\in G$:

$$(a\circ b)^{-1}=b^{-1}\circ a^{-1}.$$

Let $a,b\in X$. Since $x^{-1}=x$ for all $x\in X$, we have that

$$a\circ b=(a\circ b)^{-1}=b^{-1}\circ a^{-1}=b\circ a.$$

Hence $\circ$ is commutative (QED), and $(X,\circ)$ is an Abelian group.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that every element has a symmetric with respect to $\circ$, the symmetric of $x\in X$ being $x$.

Let $(x,y)\in X^2$, one has: $$x\circ y\circ x^{-1}\circ y^{-1}=x\circ y\circ (y\circ x)^{-1}=(x\circ y)^2=e.$$
Therefore, $x\circ y=y\circ x$.

Comment: Am I wrong saying that $x\circ x=e$ implies that $x$ is its own inverse?

Comment: OK, that is an argument, sorry. That makes the proof much easier. Nevertheless, a proof without inverses is also possible.

Comment: You are right, both of them have their own interests! :)

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can I say that it is its own inverse?

Comment: Yes, you can! For all $x\in X$, if you let $y=x$, then $x\circ y=e=y\circ x$, which means that $y=x^{-1}$.

Comment: Why is (x,y) in X^2?

Comment: This only means that I take $x$ in $X$ and $y$ in $X$.

Comment: I don't understand the step where you say that $x\circ y\circ(y\circ x)^{-1}=(x\circ y)^2$.